# iPad simulator 6.0 page orientation not working

Tags: xcode, ipad, cordova, ios-simulator, orientation

I recently upgraded xcode to 4.5 which installed iPad 6.0. Now when I run PhoneGap html5 app in it the page inside simulator is not rotating, it was working with earlier version of xcode. When I change simulator from portrait to landscape the html page of app remains in portrait, it does not rotate to landscape with simulator.

Comment: Have you checked your settings since the update? make sure the target settings support the orientations you want to use, as well as the devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

Edit AppDelegate.m:

Find:
[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];

replace with the following code:

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

If you're still displaying the statusbar then inside: 
MainViewController.m:

After
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
```

add

```
self.webView.frame = CGRectMake ( 0, 15, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-15);
```

Might not be the best fix, but it worked for me!